# How to embed youtube RTSP video into my website

Tags: php, video, youtube, streaming, rtsp

I've website that made for blackberry visitors and it should shows youtube video and indeed since it is blackberry i can get youtube videos through `m.youtube.com` with the following format

*Example* :

```
rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwnUg6yvPB1bKxMYESARFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

*My question*

How to embed this video link format so that it works on my website for my blackberry visitors rather then clicking on the video link !!

Comment: You are building a website for just one smartphone? This is nuts.

Comment: @jamjam :) you won't believe it ! it not only for smartphone users but it also specified for certain users in certain village in my country !! a kind of helping website to let strangers know roads,rest houses,farms,stores ..etc.